# Fixing erlang 15B Observer (from macports); fails to run

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets

Following the instructions at the [Observer User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html), I tried to run the Observer application.

```
$ erl -sname observer -hidden -setcookie MyCookie -run observer
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{wx_object,start,[observer_wx,[],[]],[]},{observer_wx,start,0,[{file,"observer_wx.erl"},{line,64}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Is there a known fix for this? Something I neglected to install?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WxWidget on Mac OS X is currently 32-bit only.  It won't work with a 64-bit erlang installation.  That's why you get the error message that wx_object:start is undef'd.

You'll need to build a 32-bit version of erlang.

I think newer versions of wxWidgets can be built 64-bit on Mac OS X, but i'm not sure if they are compatible with erlang's wx library.

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Mint distribution, I had to install the necessary packages by performing the following command before installing R15B03 via evm:

`sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libpng3`

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Installation).